# Connect Marketing cloud with Sales Cloud for multiple Business Units

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

I have 9 Business Units in Marketing Cloud and I have 1 user that is integrated with Sales Cloud. Now initially I had 2 BUs in MC and those 2 BUs were integrated with SC during Connector set up. Now, that I have more BUs in MC and I want to include those in SC as well, I logged in to SC -> Marketing Cloud -> Configure Marketing cloud Connector -> Manage Business Units

I am getting this error on SC:

> Sorry, something went wrong.We weren't able to retrieve your business
>   units. Check to make sure you have permission to access these business
>   units and try again. Need more help? Turn on logging and open a
>   support case in the Help and Training portal.

And to clarify here itself, no permissions were changed. The permissions I had earlier when I integrated those 2 BUs, same set of permissions I possess now, too.

Since the new BUs are not integrated with SC, I am unable to trigger journeys in MC on creation /updation of objects.

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and not reaching to any solution, I refreshed the selected Business Units by removing them, saving and the adding and saving again. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to raise the case with SFMC support. I have seen these issues, and support needs to toggle some backend settings to reset the SC and SFMC connection.